# Uploaded image to Heroku app not uploading to s3

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-s3, heroku, file-upload

I have a website that admin can add images of products to. Heroku deletes said images after a couple of hours so I'm trying to implement AWS s3, to keep images from getting deleted. I'm using multer to upload images.

This is the multer upload .js

```js
import express from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import { isAuth, isAdmin } from "../utils";
import uploadAws from "../uploadAws";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}.jpg`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
const uploadRouter = express.Router();

uploadRouter.post("/", isAuth, isAdmin, upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(201).send({ image: `/${req.file.path}` });
  uploadAws( `/${req.file.path}`, `${Date.now()}.jpg`);
});

export default uploadRouter;
```

And this is the piece for uploading to AWS

```js
import config from "./config";

const fs = require("fs");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const uploadAws = (path, image) => {

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: config.AWS_ID,
    secretAccessKey: config.AWS_KEY,
  });

  const BUCKET_NAME = "emy-bucket";

  const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: image, // File name you want to save as in S3
      Body: fileContent,
    };

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
  };

  uploadFile(path);
};

export default uploadAws;
```

here is axios post from api.js file

```js
export const uploadProductImage = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const { token } = getUserInfo();
    const response = await axios({
      url: `${apiUrl}/api/uploads`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      data: formData,
    });
    if (response.statusText !== "Created") {
      throw new Error(response.data.message);
    } else {
      return response.data;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err.response.data.message || err.message };
  }
};
```

The image will upload to the website but not to AWS, any help would be great.

Comment: The code looks good, any log you can share? Did you configure the access to the bucket?

Comment: I have configured access with a .env file also I have an empty file "uploads" that all uploaded images is sent to, but of course heroku deletes them after dyno cycle. I get the 201 post from image being uploaded

Comment: 201 because the POST works, but the communication with S3 seems to be your problem. Do you have any log? If you have your AWS credentials in a `.env` it is better to Heroku ConfigVars (I assume you commit/push the .env which is never a good idea)

Comment: I have the .env file in gitignore, it's never pushed. The config file uses AWS_ID: process.env.AWS_ID and AWS_KEY:process.env.AWS_KEY. But even when I add it to the pushed uploadAWS file it's not added to s3, const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '****************',
    secretAccessKey: '*********************',
    region: "us-east-1",
  });